# How does one print to the command line in r?

Tags: r

How does one print to the command line in r? I googled the question and it turned up nothing. One of the tasks for a project was to print a table to the command line as a list. I have all the code working, and everything displaying properly I just don't understand what in the world "print to the command line means." All this time we have been knitting to html and/or running r chunks within r markdown.

Here is the code where I am printing if it helps. Nothing special about the table. It is a bare-bones m x n table turned into a list.

```
l = list(table)
print(l)
```

Comment: What about this code doesn't do what you want? Where are you running it, in a script?

Comment: I think the title of this question is misleading -- it should be about the console, not the command line, as both are two different things.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to **print**, just type:

```
l
```

Answer (score 0):

By "(...) print to the command line", the person writing the instructions for your project probably meant: output to the R terminal.

By default, R outputs to the terminal. So you don't have anything special to do.

For instance,

```
list(table)
```

will output the list to your terminal. (Note that the list does not exist as an object. It only exists as a terminal output).

If you assign the result of some code to an object (with `<-` or `=`), then the output is re-directed from the terminal to the newly created object.

So

```
l <- list(table)
```

will create the object `l` with your list, but will not output anything to the terminal. To output your object, you just call it:

```
l
```

If you want to output to the terminal AND create an object at the same time, you enclose the expression in parentheses:

```
(l <- list(table))
```

will create the object `l` and output its content to the terminal.